# Missing output when executing subprocess in java code

Tags: java, c++, process

I was building a java GUI around a simple C++ program, and it turned out I can execute it only once. I want to be able to run it every time I click on a button, but for some reason it won't start

I did *my best* to make a simplified case to reproduce this bug. The following code should print out "I'm running" ten times. Instead, some occurrences are missing.

Why? What is required for it to work reliably?

---

**The java code:**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./a.out");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Process p = null;
            String output;
            try {
                // Run a.out
                p = pb.start();

                // Gather the output
                InputStream opt = p.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[opt.available()];
                opt.read(buffer, 0, opt.available());
                output = new String(buffer);

            } catch(IOException ex) {}

            // Print it
            System.out.println(output);
            p.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**The C++ program code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"I'm running";
}
```

**Output:**

```
I'm running
I'm running



I'm running
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're going for. You want a Java GUI with a button that allows you to start a program when you clikc that button? Where's your GUI code?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes. No need for GUI code, because i know it works - It starts process after first click, but after next clicks it doesn't. You can see simplified case here. It should cout "I'm running" 10 times. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you are running starts working asynchronously. And sometimes that c++ program is not fast enough to print the output - you are terminating it while it is initializing, or starting the writing process.

You should read its output once it is finished. The naive approach would be to add a call to `Process.waitFor()` right after you created the process - this will work for the case you described in your statement.

However this approach has a very large issue - the program you are running may run out of output buffer, and it will have to wait until you consume its output, thus never terminating. So if the program you are running is more complicated, then you have to write the logic, that will do both - consume the output and wait until the program has completed its work. Here is the example:

```
p = pb.start();
InputStream opt = p.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
while (!p.waitFor(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
    while ((bytesRead = opt.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        boas.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
// Reading the final part of the output 
while ((bytesRead = opt.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    boas.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
s = new String(boas.toByteArray());
System.out.println(s);
```